# Using html react parse throws error when "(e.g., ..)" is in the text

Tags: html, reactjs, parsing

I have tried using both html-react-parse and react-html-parse, both examples throw same error:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('e.g.,') is not a valid name.

Here is the code snippet simplified, my input is coming from search results and text is being outputted as the "highlight" of the search result, but I have simplified it here to reproduce:

```
import React from "react";
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
//import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser";

export function App(props) {
  function getSearchHighlight(highlight) {
    try {
      return parse(highlight);
      //return ReactHtmlParser(highlight);
    } catch (e) {
      return "Issues with search highlight " + e;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello React Parse.</h1>
      <p>
        {getSearchHighlight(
          "Comparison to this and that <em>information</em> (e.g., those surveys)."
        )}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
// Log to console
console.log("Hello console");
```

Tried using other dangerouslyset, but we do not want to use that.

Expecting it not to break/throw error on normal text (currently thinking that its html)

Comment: [Works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-fog-kq3qtg?file=/src/App.js).  Are you using a specific version of `react-html-parser`?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which produces the error?

Comment: Thank-you for confirming, its within a much larger project, this is as simple as I could make it. The version I was using is "1.4.14". Actualy also using the commented out lline (Parse) and that import parse from 'html-react-parser'; ... not the other one... It must just be the format of my input, escaping, of it or something that is making the parse identify that part as an element :(